# Core Data & iCloud: exception when NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification received

Tags: ios, core-data, objective-c-blocks, icloud, nsoperationqueue

I'm following the Apple's [iCloud Programming Guide for Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH3-SW6), the `Using the SQLite Store with iCloud` section, and you are told there to listen for the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification` iCloud event this way:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification
                                                  object:self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                  [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
                                                      // disable user interface with setEnabled: or an overlay

                                                      if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
                                                          NSError *saveError;
                                                          if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&saveError]) {
                                                              NSLog(@"Save error: %@", saveError);
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                      else {
                                                          // drop any managed object references
                                                          [self.managedObjectContext reset];
                                                      }
                                                  }];
                                              }];
```

I've put such code within my `AppDelegate`'s `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method and, when the notification is received, I get this exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can only use -performBlock: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.'
```

According to the document, this should work... what could am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error:

```
Can only use -performBlock: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.
```

...is quite clear. You cannot call `performBlock:` on a managed object context unless that context was created using one of the queue-type concurrency options. Meaning that when you created the context, you must have used `initWithConcurrencyType:` **and** used either `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` as the argument.

This has nothing at all to do with the notification, only with the fact that you're calling `performBlock:` when you didn't create the context correctly.